# Tool to watch other ttys for linux?

Tags: linux, root, tty, administration

BSD systems have a neat [watch](http://www.bsdguides.org/2005/watch-terminal-activity/) tool for snooping other ttys :

> Have you ever had a user login to your box and then ask you for help? Or have you ever been curious as to what your users are doing on your system? The watch(8) utility will let you snoop another tty, allowing you to see what your other users are doing and even interact with them. It’s a must-have utility for every network administrator.

Unfortunately `watch` is a different beast on linux.

So far I've got:

- `ttysnoop` requires modifying /etc/inittab which is a pain
- `conspy` couldn't get it to work so far
- `peekfd` works but only one way (you can see user input but not output)
- `screen` is nice of course but user needs to use screen ...

Isn't there a good equivalent for linux ?

Comment: I'm sure someone must have written a systemtap script for this ...

Comment: Ah, [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281432/28431) it is.

Comment: cached link for `watch`: http://web.archive.org/web/20160208172321/http://www.bsdguides.org/2005/watch-terminal-activity/

Answer (score 3):

#### ptysnoop via SystemTap

Install [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/), create [ptysnoop](http://stapbofh.krunch.be/ptysnoop.stp) file:

```
#!/usr/bin/stap

probe kernel.function("pty_write") {
    if (kernel_string($tty->name) == @1) {
            printf("%s", kernel_string_n($buf, $c))
    }
}
```

Make it executable. Now to watch `/dev/pts/6` you just `sudo ptysnoop pts6`

#### ttyrpld

> [ttyrpld](http://ttyrpld.sourceforge.net/desc.php) is a multi-os kernel-level tty logger (key and screenlogger for ttys) with (a)synchronous replay support. It supports most tty types, including vc, bsd and unix98-style ptys (xterm/ssh), serial, isdn, etc. Being implemented within the kernel makes it unavoidable for the default user. It runs with no overhead if the logging daemon is not active.

You need a kernel module for it though.

#### ttylogger

I <del>ended</del> started up writing a small strace-based [ttylogger](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/ttylogger) tool which works well for my needs. All you need is perl and strace and then `sudo ttylogger pid`.

Use this with user shell's pid to dump output from all subsequent commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple file descriptors for `peekfd`.

e.g.

```
peekfd -n -8 -d -c 24184 0 1 2
```

will snoop on stdin, stdout, and stderr of pid 24184.

The `-c` option will also attach to any child processes.  This is necessary in order to see the ouput from them (e.g. seeing the output of `ls` that has been run in a snooped-on shell process)

Strangely, I find that it always successfully attaches to the child  (no matter what child process I run in the snooped-on tty - `ls`, `uname`, `/bin/echo` as opposed to the built-in `echo`) but also always prints an error message `Error attaching to pid -38` (and the "pid" is **always** -38).

`man peekfd` says:

> DIAGNOSTICS
>
> The following diagnostics may be issued on stderr:
>
> ```
>   Error attaching to pid ...
> ```
>
> An unknown  error  occurred  while  attempted  to  attach  to  a process..  you may need to be root.

Looks like a bug to me - I am running `peekfd` as root, and it **always** prints the error message, always with that same bogus (`-38`) PID.

BEWARE: the man page also says:

> BUGS
>
> Probably  lots.   Don't  be surprised if the process you are monitoring dies.

Comment: Neat, terminal output is almost perfect. peekfd seems to interfere with the shell though, ^C at the prompt does nothing while it's running for example.

Comment: you must be trapping ^C or something because ^C kills peekfd for me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ^C in the shell's window

Comment: ah, right. i see what you mean.  yes, that is broken.

Comment: Also it doesn't work for pipes (dumps output from all processes !)